# closed -- Couldn't build Vuetify v2.2 with sass error

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Hi I am using custom components on Vuetify v2.2, which are throwing error during build.
I can't figure out, what's the problem with Vuetify v2.2
because Vuetify v2.1.15 was working well.

Thrown error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VCalendar/VCalendarDaily.sass (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VCalendar/VCalendarDaily.sass)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VCalendar/VCalendarDaily.sass:1:257
    at stringifyNode (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss-value-parser/lib/stringify.js:2:19)
    at Function.stringify (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss-value-parser/lib/stringify.js:45:10)
    at Gradient.colorStops (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/hacks/gradient.js:503:26)
    at Gradient.oldWebkit (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/hacks/gradient.js:396:10)
    at Gradient.replace (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/hacks/gradient.js:89:30)
    at Gradient.add (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/value.js:148:20)
    at Gradient.add (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/hacks/gradient.js:570:35)
    at Gradient.process (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/prefixer.js:155:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/processor.js:379:36
    at /home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:190:18
    at /home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:135:18
    at Rule.each (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:101:16)
    at Rule.walk (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:131:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:148:24
    at Root.each (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:101:16)
    at Root.walk (/home/ubuntu/chainflix-nuxt-tar/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:131:17)
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VCalendar/VCalendarDaily.sass 4:14-213
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCalendar/VCalendarDaily.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCalendar/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./components/inc/vuetifyCustom/CTextarea/CTextarea.js
 @ ./components/inc/vuetifyCustom/CTextarea/index.js
 @ ./plugins/GlobalComponent.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
```

In `CTextarea` I imported `VTextarea` and `VInput` like this:

```js
import { VTextarea, VInput } from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/components/VTextarea/VTextarea.sass'
import { CTextField } from '../CTextField'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'CTextarea',
  extends: VTextarea.extend(),
 ///// etc custom codes
})
```

I think this error has some correlation with sass & postcss.
I hope to Build Successfully.

I must using Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies options in custom components.

My package dependencies & devDependencies

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.6.3",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.8.0",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "base64toblob": "0.0.2",
    "bigdecimal": "^0.6.1",
    "camelcase-keys": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.6",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "filestream": "^4.1.3",
    "firebase": "^7.5.2",
    "form-data": "^2.5.1",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
    "ip-regex": "^4.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.10.2",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.3",
    "snakecase-keys": "^2.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.1",
    "vue-drag-drop": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-google-charts": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.0",
    "vue-lottie": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-ls": "^3.2.1",
    "vue-qrcode": "^0.2.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuejs-logger": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
    "@nuxt/babel-preset-app": "^2.10.2",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^0.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.10.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "sass": "^1.23.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  },
}
```

- If you need more informations, comment please. I really hope to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `postcss-loader` package in your dependencies. 
Have you tried installing it?

```sh
npm i -D postcss-loader
```

Personally i would prefer using the `node-sass` and `sass-loader` package as suggested in the nuxt docs: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/pre-processors/

```sh
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: postcss-loader is included with nuxt. so not need to install again.
and sass and sass-loader was installed with @nuxtjs/vuetify. so that is not need, too

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed.

This problem was my mistakes with Treeshakes.

so I fixed variable scss files and components direct import.

I hope someones are helpful with this.

In components

```js
// wrong
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib'

// Correct
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VTextField'
```

In variable scss files. May you imported `@import 'vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';`
That is need just a time in root file ( In [webpack guild](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables#webpack-install)'s options.prependData or options.data. )

```
@import 'vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
// some global values
// some components values
```

And... Use map-deep-merge, when you should fix color or such value in Object type(?).

```
$purple: ();
$purple: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'base': #6255c5
  ),
  $purple
);

$shades: ();
$shades: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'black': #2D2935,
    'white': #FFFFFF
  ),
  $shades
);
```

Happy coding!